# Вывод данных в listView jQuery

Tags: jquery, дизайн, javascript

Добрый день всем. У меня тут не получается вывести красиво в листВью данные из js функции. Пытаюсь вывести при помощи [jQuery Mobile Alpha 3](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/#docs/lists/docs-lists.html), вывести пытаюсь вот таким кодом:

JS код

```
 var $taskli = $('<li><a href="\">Task Name ' + task.id + ": " + task.time + "</a></li>").appendTo($("#tasks"));
 var $taskul = $("<ul/>").appendTo($taskli);
```

html код

```
<ul id="tasks" data-role="listview" data-theme="g"></ul>
```

Выводит не так как в примере на сайте jQuery, а обычным списком, без возможности нажатия. Как можно вывести из кода так что бы нормально показывалось?[image]

а хочется вот так:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS

```
   var taskli = '<li><a href="\">Task Name ' + task.id + ": " + task.time + "</a></li>";
   $('#tasks').append(taskli).listview('refresh');
```

HTML

```
<ul id="tasks" data-role="listview"></ul>
```